# Which is correct, you will find or you will consider?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, writing-style, writing

What is the correct way to write the following sentences?

1. We hope that you will consider the school welcoming, willing to listen and willing to respond to your questions.
2. We hope you will find the school welcoming, willing to listen and willing to respond to your questions.

The second sentence is my attempt. The first sentence is my principal's attempt.

Comment: Both are correct. 'Consider' refers to the visitor forming an opinion of the school, 'find' refers to the impression they receive. They are slightly different ways of expressing the same idea.

Comment: Also, *that* is optional.

Comment: I'd consider the use of 'find' more welcoming here. And it encompasses the 'form an opinion = come to consider' meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Edwin--in short, "find" is more welcoming and *friendly*.

In all honesty, "We hope that you will consider the school welcoming..." seems a bit aggressive and, in some cases, may imply that there is some unspoken penalty if they do not consider your school to fit those criteria. I'll compare it to a mob boss blackmailing a detective: "We hope you'll consider us to be law-abiding citizens." (That's an exaggerated comparison, of course, but I only brought it up to clarify how it can be perceived as slightly hostile and/or defensive).

"Find", on the other hand, is more subtle and considerate. It emphasizes their  *natural discovery* of those qualities in the school's environment without any sort of coercion, bribery, or outside influence.